# Paypal Classic API error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to integrated codeigniter and paypal classic adaptive payment API

it was working fine on sandbox, when I switched it to real live

it returns

```
array(11) { ["responseEnvelope.timestamp"]=> string(29) "2014-01-14T18:22:40.663-08:00" ["responseEnvelope.ack"]=> string(7) "Failure" ["responseEnvelope.correlationId"]=> string(13) "76ca75a2250ac" ["responseEnvelope.build"]=> string(7) "7935900" ["error(0).errorId"]=> string(6) "560022" ["error(0).domain"]=> string(8) "PLATFORM" ["error(0).subdomain"]=> string(11) "Application" ["error(0).severity"]=> string(5) "Error" ["error(0).category"]=> string(11) "Application" ["error(0).message"]=> string(60) "The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value" ["error(0).parameter(0)"]=> string(23) "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" }
```

highly appreciate for comments

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty straight forward.  You're apparently passing an invalid value for your App ID.  Have you filled anything in for that at all when you send live calls?  What exactly are you sending?